# NativeScript automatic sms listening | Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript

I'm trying to implement a SMS receiver that will work on both Android and iOS as I am developing on the NativeScript framework, this needs to automatically listen for SMS's containing OTP, similar to the functionality WhatsApp has.

I've already attempted the following plugin : [NativeScript SMS Receiver](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-sms-receiver/), this is primarily for Android implementation, and also doesn't seem to be functioning correctly.

ListeningClass.ts:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  console.log("In OTP");
  // register Sms Listener to get SMS callbacks
  SmsReceiver.getInstance().registerListeners(
      function () {
        console.log("Listening started");
        // onSMSReceiverStarted
      }.bind(this),
      function (exception) {
        console.log("Listening failed");
        console.log(exception)
        // onSMSReceiverFailed
      }.bind(this),
      function (message) {
        // onSMSReceived
        // handle sms here
        // deregister Sms Listener to avoid invalid operations
        console.log("recieved");
        SmsReceiver.getInstance().deregisterListeners();
      }.bind(this),
      function () {
        // onSMSReceiverTimeOut
        console.log("listening failed on OTP");
      }.bind(this)
  );

  // start sms receiver for single message
  SmsReceiver.getInstance().startReceiver();
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.pravinkumarputta.android.smsreceiver.SMSBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```